# Removing blank lines between output lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to format a document. Each line needs to be 158 spaces long regardless of if there is information or not. I'm getting the correct output I need but it's printing additional lines in between.

Example: I should expect to see,

```
1
2
3
4
```

and instead I get:

```
1

2

3

4
```

I've tried rstrip() and that removes the additional blank line but also removes the spaces I need for formatting.

```
   for line in f1:

    #removes leading white spaces
        line.strip()
    #finds the length of the line
        x = (len(line))
    #hard set value for the type of document
        y = 158
    #finding the difference between string length and hard value
        z = (y - x)
    #prints the difference and string length
        Str1 = line.ljust(z)
        print (Str1)
```

I'd like each line to be exactly 158 characters long and have zero spaces in between each line. Currently I can either get spaces or 158 character lines, not both.

Comment: Have you tried `line = line.strip()`? The `strip()` function is not an in-place operation, but it does get rid of the newlines that might be already on your string.

Comment: you can print '\b' and even try the end="" in print statement

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in f1:

#removes leading white spaces
    line.strip()
#finds the length of the line
    x = (len(line))
#hard set value for the type of document
    y = 158
#finding the difference between string length and hard value
    z = (y - x)
#prints the difference and string length
    Str1 = line.ljust(z)
    print (Str1,end="")
```

end="" will not create one more "\n" and your output will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
line.replace("\n\n", "\n")
```